# Decomposition of semisimple Lie algebra via its roots

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Exercise 14.33 in Fulton and Harris's *Representation Theory* claims that

If the roots of a semisimple Lie algebra lie in a collection of mutually orthogonal subsets, one sees that the Lie algebra decomposes into a direct sum accordingly.

Although intuitively I can see why this is true, could anybody direct me to a proof of this assertion, or outline how I should go about doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you only want hints, so here are some:

**Hint 1:** Compute $(\alpha+\beta,\alpha)$ and $(\alpha+\beta,\beta)$ for $\alpha$, $\beta$ taken from one of the orthogonal subsets.

**Hint 1.5:** Deduce that $\alpha+\beta$ is not a root.

**Hint 2:** Use that $[\mathfrak{g}_\alpha,\mathfrak{g}_\beta]=\mathfrak{g}_{\alpha+\beta}$.

**Hint 3:** Take $\mathfrak{g}^i$ to be the some of all $\mathfrak{g}_\alpha$ in one of the orthogonal subsets.

Comment: Thank you for the hints. I still do not follow, and am a bit confused on how I get the decomposition from this. Could you write in more detail?

Comment: @user64913 I've added 2 more hints.

Comment: So far my argument is: for $\alpha, \beta\in S$, $\alpha+\beta$ is not a root since it's neither in $S$ or perpendicular to it. So $[\mathfrak{g}_\alpha,\mathfrak{g}_\beta]=\mathfrak{g}_{\alpha+\beta}=0$, and letting $\mathfrak{g}^i=\bigoplus_{\alpha \in S}{\mathfrak{g}_\alpha}$ we have $\mathfrak{g}=\bigoplus \mathfrak{g}_i$. Is this what you had in mind? Seems too short to be true, ha.

Comment: @user64913 This is what I had in mind, yes.

Comment: Details from here: http://www.math.harvard.edu/archive/128_spring_04/handouts/chaptersix.pdf